# Variations: Propagate Lists Programmatically

Tags: 2013, publishing-site, variations

I have defined variations with two Labels (source and target)

I have selected **"Publishing Sites and List with variations and all pages"** in one of the settings. The pages are created in the target site but the Lists doesn't seem to propagate. Until and unless I go to List and define it under variations from UI.

Found the option to make it under Variations (screenshot below)

[image: SharePoint 2013: Variation List Propagation]

**How can I do this programmatically when a new List is created, it should by default be under Variations..?**

**Is there a configuration way?**

Comment: any solutions found?

Comment: Nop, I ended up creating lists in Target site programmatically on [ListAdded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splisteventreceiver.listadded.aspx) event receiver

Comment: In that way, will you still have the synch of list items between source and target?

Comment: Nop, in our case we didn't want Items to be propagated.. since data in them will eventually be changed completely for the target sites.. But to sync list items, you will need ItemAdded event receiver, it won't be automatic..

Comment: Do u know why in some lists there is no the Variations ribbon?

Comment: Not sure.. Maybe some kinds of lists don't support Variation.. It's still a black box.. :)

Answer (score 5):

Take a look to this link that explain How propagation works:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/sharepoint_quick_reads/archive/2013/08/12/sharepoint-2013-variations-content-synchronization-between-source-and-target-variations.aspx

Also check the timer jobs that are responsible of the propagations and the Variations log.

From the link:

> Custom lists and Libraries are by default not propagated to target
>   labels. To propagate custom list/libraries, go to List and Variations
>   tab, click settings and select labels where custom list needs to be
>   created and synced. Once labels are selected, next Variations
>   Propagate Sites and Lists Job Definition will create list in target
>   labels.
>
> Once list/library becomes part of variation system, SharePoint adds a
>   new Approval Status column to control publishing and propagation on
>   List items.

Comment: I already know how to do it from UI.. I want to do it programmatically from SharePoint Object Model..

Answer (score 1):

Take a look to this method: [**SyncList()**](https://github.com/GSoft-SharePoint/Dynamite/blob/develop/Source/GSoft.Dynamite/Globalization/Variations/VariationSyncHelper.cs). We implemented this behavior  using reflection (SPWebs follow the same pattern with **SyncWeb()** method)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively we ended up creating lists in Target site programmatically on [ListAdded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splisteventreceiver.listadded.aspx) event receiver